# Is the amount of invoking of the doCancel callback the same with the amount of invoking of the doOnSubscribe after terminating of the observable?

Tags: rx-java

So, the question is in the title.
Here's just a small snippet that illustrates my assumption.

Consider a chain like the following:

```
var c = 0
fun getItemsFromDb(): Observable<Data>

getItemsFromDb()
  .doOnSubscribe { c++ }
  .doOnCancel { c-- }
```

Is there guarantee, that, in the end, when the observable is completely terminated, `c == 0` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `doOnCancel` is only invoked if there was an actual cancellation, for example:

```kotlin
getItemsFromDb()
  .doOnSubscribe { c++ }
  .doOnCancel { c-- }
  .take(1)
  .subscribe()
```

Here, `take(1)` will issue a cancellation after one item so `c == 0` at the end.

```kotlin
var d = getItemsFromDb()
  .delaySubscription(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.io())
  .doOnSubscribe { c++ }
  .doOnCancel { c-- }
  .subscribe()

Thread.sleep(1000)

d.dispose()
```

Here, the consumer side is manually disposed, which in turn will invoke `doOnCancel` again, resulting in `c == 0` at the end.

If you want to invoke some callback in any case, use `doFinally`:

```kotlin
getItemsFromDb()
  .doOnSubscribe { c++ }
  .doFinally { c-- }
```